# PHP - Split (ul) List When it's in the Middle

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to split an ul into 2 when it's in the middle of the list. So when I have 50 items, create a different `ul` at 25 items and put the other remaining 25 in the second UL.

I have figured out the math to get the number where to split it, but I'm stuck at the part of creating the second `ul`. I've tried counting them, and create a second `ul` at 0 (beginning) and middle, but that didn't seem to work out as the closing tag will then be missing.

Here's what I currently have:

```
$counter = 0;
while ($dev = $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if(round(($devs->rowCount() * 50) / 100) == $counter || $counter == 0) echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>' . $dev['displayname'] . '</li>';
    if(round(($devs->rowCount() * 50) / 100) == $counter || $counter == 0) echo '</ul>';
    $counter++;
}
```

How can I make a second `ul` when it reaches the very middle of the `ul` in the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify it by using a few things - always output the open and close outside of the loop, store a value for the count so you don't have to keep on calling a method for each test...

```
$counter = 0;
$size = $devs->rowCount();
echo "<ul>";
while ($dev = $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<li>' . $dev['displayname'] . '</li>';
    $counter++;
    if(ceil($size /2) == $counter ) 
        echo '</ul><ul>';
}
echo "/<ul>";
```

I've also changed the `round()` to `ceil()` so that if there are 3 items, the split comes after the second one.

You could also add an extra test - something like

```
if(ceil($size /2) == $counter && $size > 2 )
```

Which will mean you will only get the split if there are a few items (change to whatever value you wish)

Answer (score 0):

You should try [chunking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) your query array:

```
$dev = $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$final = array_chunk ( $dev , 50, TRUE );
print_r($final);
```

Then you can fine tune according to size since the last chunk will be < 50

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$displayNames = [];
while ($dev = $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $displayNames[] = $dev['displayname'];
}

$size = count($displayNames) >> 1;
echo '<ul><li>',implode('</li><li>',array_slice($displayNames,0,$size)),'</li></ul>';
echo '<ul><li>',implode('</li><li>',array_slice($displayNames,$size)),'</li></ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to separate your data retrieval from your display code - this is exactly the kind of problem that's hard to solve when those two sides are too closely tied together.

```
// Retrieve data
while ($dev = $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $items[] = $dev['displayname'];
}

// Split into two columns
$columns = array_chunk($items, intval((count($items) + 1) / 2));

// Deal with each column separately
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($column as $item) {
        echo '<li>', $item;
    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditionals for the opening and closing `<ul>` are a bit of extra work. `count * 50 / 100` is the same as `count / 2`. Other than the mentioned `array_chunk`, you can use a standard `for` loop to count and `echo` a `<ul>` at the midway point:

```
echo '<ul>';

for ($i = 0; $i < $devs->rowCount(); $i++) {
    echo '<li>' . $devs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['displayname'] . '</li>'; 

    if ($i === ~~($devs->rowCount() / 2)) {
        echo '</ul><ul>';
    }
}

echo '</ul>';
```